# How to write \$V_{\text{a0}}\$, \$V_{\text{ab}}\$ and \$V_{\text{cm}}\$ for the three-phase three-level inverter in terms of the switching signals?

Tags: power-electronics, pwm, common-mode

How to write \$V_{\text{a0}}\$, \$V_{\text{ab}}\$ and \$V_{\text{cm}}\$ for the three-phase three-level inverter in terms of the switching signals?

For the three-phase two-level inverter, the values can be written (assuming the switching signal takes  values of either 0 or 1 based on the state (ON or OFF) as:
$$V_{\text{a0}} =  V_\text{DC}(\text{S}_1-\frac{1}{2})$$
$$V_{\text{ab}} = V_\text{DC}(\text{S}_1 - \text{S}_3)$$
$$V_{\text{cm}} = \frac{1}{3}V_\text{DC}(\text{S}_1 + \text{S}_3 + \text{S}_5)-\frac{1}{2}V_\text{DC}$$

Three-phase two-level and three-level topologies are shown below:
[image]

Fig. ref: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/sps/powersys/ref/universalbridge.html

[image]

Fig. ref: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/sps/ref/threelevelconverterthreephase.html

The scope shows signals and numerical measurements for the three-level inverter. Signals are (from top to bottom), \$\text{S}_{1}\$, \$\text{S}_{2}\$, \$V_{\text{a0}}\$, \$V_{\text{ab}}\$ and \$V_{\text{cm}} = \frac{1}{3}(V_{\text{a0}} + V_{\text{b0}} + V_{\text{c0}})\$

[image]